# Convert Date Value to Timestamp - Post Request - Ember.js

Tags: javascript, date, ember.js

My handlebars code is as followed.

```
{{bootstrap-datepicker value=from placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"}}
```

Here the user picks a date from a calendar to get the `from` date. This is for a form.

My problem is the format is as followed: `Sun May 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`
and the post request requires milliseconds since epoch format.

SO

all the code sample I've seen to fix these problems, require the date in the function.

example:

```
var myDate="26-02-2012";
myDate=myDate.split("-");
var newDate=myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[2];
alert(new Date(newDate).getTime());
```

or

```
function toTimestamp(year,month,day,hour,minute,second){
    var datum = new Date(Date.UTC(year,month-1,day,hour,minute,second));
    return datum.getTime()/1000;
}
```

or

```
var fromFormat = moment('from').fromFormat(moment(), 'milliseconds');
```

but I only have the name value as it changes all the time.

I've got moment-js, date-picker and a couple other add-ons. Any resources or code snippets will be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is `timestamp format`?

Comment: @PhilVarg  
Timestamp format = milliseconds since epoch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out with some help from friends.
I created an action that took the formatted date from `date-picker` and transformed it into UNIX time in milliseconds.

```
actions: {
    PublishForm{
          var fromDate = moment(from).valueOf(); 
    }    
}
```

**I've changed it this way due to issues displaying the date with the bootstrap-datepicker when you use the changeDate.

Comment: This solution works, but it does have it's `bugs`. Meaning if no date is selected it will send todays date, which could be problematic. Instead of making the field required, I added a if statement to check if the field was empty and if it was empty to send nothing.